# how to hide the buttons in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

When the user login to the page i have to show the logout button. I have written the logout in the header. How to disable it
I have tried ng-show and ng-hide. But the button are not showing after I set the visibility to true

```
<button ng-show="visibility">logout</button>
```

In my controller class, I am setting the visibility of the button once the user login in to the app

```
$scope.visibility = true;
```

Comment: Are they in the same scope? I.e. is there a controller set for the button

Comment: yes. they are in the same controller

Comment: Have you verified that `$scope.visibility = true;` is actually called?

Comment: It is probably a callback issue and you need to call $scope.$apply. Share your controller code.

Comment: you can put {{visibility}} on your html to see whether you are getting true or not. just to check.

Comment: It looks like that you don't have button in same scope. You can use of $rootScope or a service to store data and retrieve it when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is correct. See if you have put all inside the same scope, and mainly, the ng-app directive in `<html>`. Is there any code of your controller working?

As you can see here, it works:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/haoxk